# Can't minimize a fullscreen virtual machine

Tags: debian, virtualbox, cinnamon

When I have a full screen virtual machine opened I cannot minimize it. I have to put the VM in windowed mode and then minimize it.

I am using Debian Jessie as OS, Cinnamon (2.2.16) as graphical interface and Virtualbox (5.1.22 r115126).